# How do I restrict specific trac/svn users to access specific folders/trunk of SVN?

Tags: svn, trac

I have trac installed with svn. I have different trunks of projects. I want to limit few users, so that they can only access one specific trunk whichever I define.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can password-protect specific directories using the authz file of the svn server like this:

```
[proj:/branches/davesbranch]
dave = rw
```

There are [other means](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz.perdir) for accessing through Apache.  See [the book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html).

My question would be "why?"  If you're afraid they'll mess something up, that kinda goes against the idea of revision-control.  Furthermore, if you instead give developers the freedom to create as many branches as they want, then they'll [mess up their own branches instead of the trunk](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html#ftn.id582827).

Answer (score 0):

At Trac Hacks there's a plug-in called [Svnauthz File Administration plugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/SvnAuthzAdminPlugin) that might work for you.  I'm looking to do something similar myself though what I want to do is restrict different Trac projects to certain parts of the repository.  Haven't tried it yet.  Will get back to you once I do.

Comment: So I just installed the svnauthzadmin plugin and it looks to do what you need.  The admin interface allows you to specify repository paths and assign users' R/W permissions to those paths.