# TortoiseSVN - merging specific file from branch to trunk

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

I've been searching for the answer for a while, and I haven't found something which corresponds to my specific question.

I'm using TortoiseSVN 1.7.13, Subversion 1.7.10.

I'm working on a branch on a project. I have a new file which needs to be merged to the trunk. The whole branch should not be merged though, as my part of the project is not completed yet.

From what I have read, a simple right-click on the trunk folder, followed by merge, and picking the appropriate revision would do the trick.

The problem is: I don't have access to the trunk folder on my computer. Is there any other possibilities?

Comment: Maybe it will be helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455966/how-do-i-restrict-specific-trac-svn-users-to-access-specific-folders-trunk-of-sv

Comment: @LazyBadger : There is first a size concern, and then we are working on matlab and accessing path-specific files. By checking out the trunk, we would have to rename it (to avoid conflict), and I don't know how SVN would handle that.

Comment: Please elaborate " we would have to rename it (to avoid conflict)" - I really can't see point here (and know nothing about MatLab per se)